# Lexmark E210 Printer Installation Procedure

Tags: drivers, printing, lexmark

The [Lexmark E210 support site](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=product&segment=SUPPORT&productCode=LEXMARK_E210&locale=en&userlocale=EN#5) provides the printer driver for RedHat Linux systems, however, I think that is not for Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu.

[image: Lexmark E210 drivers selection]

What files and steps are needed to drive the Lexmark E210? If you have had success, please indicate this in your response and the version of Ubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: The Lexmark support site does provide the printer driver for Debian-based distributions, but buried deep inside the web pages. Have you visited the "Manuals" tab? They do have the procedures for Debian; go to Manuals > Technical Guides > Printer Drivers for UNIX & Linux Systems, jump to this section "Installing on Linspire or Debian Linux". Then search for the mentioned package. Not sure if this is considered a valid answer or not, since I can never test this myself.

Answer (score 1):

On the link, you provided you found a tar.gz file which contains ghostscript rpms, and a ppd file. You dont need the rpms, cause ghostscript is standard package in most distributions, ubuntu too. So first install `ghostscript`, (if it is not there already, and probably does), on the standard way `apt install ghostscript`. After that use the downloaded ppd to install the printer.

In `Lubuntu` You may install it by opening localhost:631 in a web browser. If you have the default flavour, you can use the gnome-control-center „Devices/Printers/Add a printer” button. Just follow the instructions and select the mentioned `Lexmark-E210-gdi.ppd` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

## Printing Success from 16.04 + Lexmark E210

**Inputs:**

- [.ppd driver: download Lexmark E210 .ppd](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=gdi&printer=Lexmark-E210&.submit=Generate%20PPD%20file&show=1&.cgifields=show&.cgifields=shortgui)
- acquire USB Printer's URI  via `sudo lpinfo -v | grep -i usb`

Example:

```
sudo lpinfo -v | grep -i usb
```

returned: direct **usb://Lexmark/E210**:
the URI is **usb://Lexmark/E210**

**Process:**

1. System Settings => Printers => +Add button

[image]

2. Select Device by fill in the URI:

[image]

3. Input [.ppd driver file](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=gdi&printer=Lexmark-E210&.submit=Generate%20PPD%20file&show=1&.cgifields=show&.cgifields=shortgui) location and follow menus to print test page.

The process was performed on a Raspbian NextCloudPi server: the printer accepts CUPS jobs sent through the LAN.

References:

- [Raspberry Pi Print Server](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-print-server)
- [How to Install Printer Drivers on Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/215235/how-to-install-printer-drivers-on-linux/)